# Wordpress shortcode with separate template/file?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm at an early stage of learning Wordpress (and shortcode), so bear with me:

To me, shortcodes seem like a swiss army knife of not having to use page-specific templates for everything. I like to build as many pages in the wysiwyg as possible, but often I would need some (reusable) php stuff for displaying stuff in a certain way.

Having googled a lot, it seems to me the way to do shortcodes is like:

```php
function caption_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
  return '<span class="caption">' . $content . '</span>';
}
```

My question is, is it possible to put the html in a separate template-ish file? It seems wrong and verbose to put all this markup here, escape quotes, et.c. Like a template-file for a shortcode, to which the shortcode can pass some Data Transfer Object (or simply just some scoped variables). So: display in template-file, logic for finding data (to pass to said template-file) in shortcode-function (wherever it may be defined, functions.php, separate plugin, or something).

Comment: In which file do you put this function now? You can include files in your functions.php like you normally do in php. So you can create any file you want.

Comment: I've put the shortcode exactly in functions.php (for the lack of knowing better) - so what you're saying is, I can pull a file (using include?) and in this file, the local variables in my function (residing in functions.php) will be available?

Comment: Keeping maintainability in mind, I'd recommend grouping all your shortcodes in a class. A good, but rather advanced example is the WC shortcodes class: https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-shortcodes.php

Comment: Thx diggy - however, this is a little off-track. I see lots of div's and escaped quotes in the Woo-source. These guys don't seem to put html outside the shortcode-functions either! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set-up views(php files) and then include partial views into those ones. Wordpress allows templates  to be includes within other templates to ensure code reuse and its easily modifiable by child themes. You can use this function to include those

```
 get_template_part( $slug );
```

However, in your case, the short code function needs to return the value to the caller function. So, this setup will not work.

Answer (score -1):

For code that effects FUNCTIONALITY, put your code in a plugin.

For APPEARANCE, put your code in your theme's template files or funtions.php file.
Many beggining WP developers lump all their code into the theme's functions.php file, this is often the wrong place for it (if that code might ever get exported to another theme, for instance). Only put code specific to a specific theme in a theme's functions.php .
To get Wordpress to recognize your plugin, create a php file and start the file like this:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: My Caption Shortcode Plugin
Description: A really cool plugin
*/

    function caption_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
        return '<span class="caption">' . $content . '</span>';
    }
?>
```

Put this file in your plugins directory (usually, you should create a sub directory for each plugin). Plugins are usually held in /wp-content/plugins/ . Then you can activate or deactive the code as a plugin, when you go to the plugins tab in the admin menu.

Of course, this plugin won't do anything as is. Remember that plugin functionality should be hooked into Wordpress via action hooks, filters, and shortcodes. For a shortcode for instance, you'd use the function add_shortcode somewhere to let Wordpress know your function is a shortcode.

Comment: Thx, Jim. I hear you on putting custom stuff in reusable plugins. Then e.g. add them as shortcodes (in my case) using add_shortcode method. But: I still see quoted html. Maybe I'm too much of a ASP.NET MVC dev (which I am!), but I feel like html should be in a file, that looks like html. Syntax-highlighting, all that. Whenever html with attributes+values gets put into 1 string (escaped and stuff) I get this bad feeling - this can't be good. I'm trying to find out, whether there's a pattern in wordpress-development for having html separate from logic (i.e. finding the data to display), et.c.

Comment: Good point, you should as practice try to keep Markup seperate from whatever content you're modifying. For instance, let's say that you had a plugin that did something trivial, like add some kind of jQuery to the content of a post. In that case, you'd use a wordpress 'filter' (as a plugin), to add your markup to the content before output, and keep the unmodified content in the DB. There is no 'standard' wordpress practice for this, but an experienced developer would want to seperate markup from content, it just depends on the specific application.

Comment: This is a distinct pattern in Wordpress for seperation of html from logic. A "THEME", controls much of the look of the site. Within a theme there are usually several PHP files which are corelates to various views. For instance, single.php is used as a template to view a single post. The codex explains it all: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy